# Session expired on form submit

Tags: html, jsp, session, servlets

There is a scenario in which I am having a form which is shown from my application as a pop up dynamically for various events. I am filling up the form and submitting it which causes session expiry.

I found out that when printing the values of the request headers in the form, i see that the jsession id is missing or sometimes new jseesion id is created.

This is not happening frequently. In working cases I am not missing any jsession id or getting differnt jseesion id's.

Any suggestions?

Below is the code sample.

```
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  </HEAD>
   <%
  Enumeration<String> headerNames = request.getHeaderNames(); 
 while (headerNames.hasMoreElements())
 { 
    String headerName = headerNames.nextElement();
  String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);
   System.out.println("Header Name   " +headerName );
  System.out.println("headerValue   " +headerValue );
 } 
 %>
 <body>
 Comments </br>
<form name = 'savefrm' action ='save.jsp'>
<textarea name = 'comments' id = 'text' cols=38 rows=8>"+comments.trim()+"</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="ok"/>
</form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Is this a separate servlet or one in an application?

Comment: No its built in servlet of the application.

Comment: You have first to exclude if this is a server or a client problem. To determine it, you'd need to track the HTTP traffic. In Chrome/IE9/Firebug you can press F12 to check the "Network" traffic. Examine the request/response headers. Try if necessary different browsers to see if behaviour is the same. If it's indeed the server which returns a new JSESSIONID cookie in response even though the client has already sent the right JSESSIONID cookie in request, then it's a server problem, otherwise it's a client problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your session timeout through web.config like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="100000"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

1000 ms = 1 second

Comment: We have set it programatically as session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);

Comment: This is not happening when session is idle.

Comment: Sorry that was for .Net environment. For Servlets you should try my second answer.

Answer (score 1):

On web.xml file :

```
<web-app>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
   </session-config>
</web-app>
```

20 = 20 minutes

Or you can do it inside the code :

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(20*60);
```

20 * 60 = 20 minutes

Comment: This is not happening when the session is idle and we set it programatically as session.setMaxInactiveInterval(-1);

Comment: Why you set it for -1 ? this step will kill the session. What you are doing is that you are trying to change the timeout to -1. SO because of that your session is killed immediately.