# Why does session expires when submit a form in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I tried to submit a specific form the session becomes expire.

**Please** don't relate this problem to the session timeout. I've tested with other forms all are working fine but when I tried to submit a specific form the sessions become expire.

Here is my `[SessionExpire]` attribute that I'm using to ensure that session is not expire.

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check  sessions here
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["createdby"] == null)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Here is my Controller action

```
[SessionExpire]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "FirmId,Name,Email,Phone,Status,CellPhone,UnitLimit,Address,PaymentDate,NextPaymentDate,Currency,NoUnit,NoProperty,ExpectedNoUnit,BusinessType,Website,ClientId,CreatedDate,CreatedBy,DeletedBy,DeletedOn,PackageId,IsCustomPackage")] FirmDM objFirm, HttpPostedFileBase fileLogo, HttpPostedFileBase fileSign)
{
     //My logic
}
```

Here is my form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Firm", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     //My input fields
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save" />
}
```

I found many questions about session expiring on Stack Overflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411790/session-expired-on-form-submit) but couldn't solve problem. I'm curious, why my session value becomes null when submit a specific form not at all?

Please ask for if need any other information.

Comment: From where you set `Session["createdby"]`??

Comment: @Umair Anwaar I'm setting my `Session` values in Login action at Account controller when user successfully login.

Comment: When you set the session value also check the expiry `Session.Timeout` and redirect to your form get action and check `Session.Timeout` again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be relevant to your IIS (or IIS express)  application's app pool idle time ... see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219169/change-session-timeout-on-iis-express)